# Entity Framework is quite slow

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I gave a simple EF query

```
return context.GlobalEntities
.Where(ge => ge.IsActive == true)  
.ToList()
```

which gets translated into the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityId] AS [GlobalEntityId], 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityName] AS [GlobalEntityName], 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityAlias] AS [GlobalEntityAlias], 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityTypeId] AS [GlobalEntityTypeId], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
[Extent1].[ChangedBy] AS [ChangedBy], 
[Extent1].[ChangedAt] AS [ChangedAt], 
[Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
[Extent1].[AverageActionTimeInHrs] AS [AverageActionTimeInHrs], 
[Extent1].[AverageCreationTimeInHrs] AS [AverageCreationTimeInHrs]
FROM [dbo].[GlobalEntity] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[IsActive]
```

When i execute the above code it takes 45 seconds to execute where as when i execute the same query from SSMS it takes only 1 sec.

Any idea on why is it taking so long for entity framework to execute a simple query. Here is what SQL profiler says

```
SQL:BatchCompleted  SELECT 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityId] AS [GlobalEntityId], 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityName] AS [GlobalEntityName], 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityAlias] AS [GlobalEntityAlias], 
[Extent1].[GlobalEntityTypeId] AS [GlobalEntityTypeId], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
[Extent1].[ChangedBy] AS [ChangedBy], 
[Extent1].[ChangedAt] AS [ChangedAt], 
[Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
[Extent1].[AverageActionTimeInHrs] AS [AverageActionTimeInHrs], 
[Extent1].[AverageCreationTimeInHrs] AS [AverageCreationTimeInHrs]
FROM [dbo].[GlobalEntity] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[IsActive]  

Application Name: EntityFramework   
NTUserName: user
CPU: 187    
Reads: 1357 
Writes: 0   
Duration: 45157 
ProcessID: 9520 
StartTime: 2012-07-06 10:38:40.797  
End TIme: 2012-07-06 10:39:25.953
```

Comment: "when i execute the same query from SSMS" do you mean the exact same query as EF generated (literally)?

Comment: And, are you executing the query against the same set of data? The same exact results are returned in both queries? Do you see this behavior on multiple successive executions without making EF "warm up" each time?